# Unable to resolve dependancy

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I am new to Android Studio, and I've installed Android Studio 3 (no previous installations), and have attempted to create a new project.

However, I am getting multiple 'unable to resolve dependency' errors being displayed

[image: details of dependency errors] 
[image: details of build.gradle (module)]
[image: details of build.gradle (project)]

I've not sure what I need to do to resolve these issues, as I've tried invalidating the cache, but this makes no difference.

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: the build.gradle files are shown in the links in the post

Comment: Don't add code in your posts behind a link, include the source code in your question on StackOverflow. This is to prevent the question from going bad once the link goes down.

Comment: Apologies for the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

add Google's Maven repository (i.e in app `build.gradle`)

```
repositories {
    google()

    // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must instead use:
    // maven {
    //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
    // }
    // An alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
}
```

More info https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven

Comment: I've altered the file, but I am still seeing the same errors.